# Cannot connect sql server among virtual machine

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, vmware

I have two virtual machine (1-2). Both of them have the same OS version(Windows Server 2012 R2) and SQL Enterprise version. However,
I can connect to server2 from server1. But can't connect to server 1.
I add exception port 1433 (SQL Server Default to firewall). How to solve this problem?
I can connect to server2 from my local computer too.

Comment: This is your eighth question, and none of them have had answers accepted. So you may want to take a moment to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). And given that half of your questions have negative scores, you may want to consider reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that 'allow remote access' hasn't been enabled. Its switched off in the installation by default for security reasons. So unless it has been turned on...

If that doesn't help, check [Microsoft's guide to troubleshooting database connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) which has some good guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one of two things :

1. Windows firewall is blocking the connection. In this case :

   ```
   Add sqlserver.exe to the firewall and it should fix it
   ```
2. Remote access is not enabled. Use the following

   ```
    sp_configure 'remote access',1
    reconfigure
   ```